# Possible images of third root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\omega$ be a primitive third root of unity.

How many distinct possible images of $\omega$ are there under all field homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Let $\eta:\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a field homomorphism.. As $\omega^3=1$ we must have $\eta(\omega)^3=1$

So, $\eta(\omega)$ is a root of unity... Possible roots of unity are $1,\omega,\omega^2$.. So, there are $3$ possible images..

But the answer is $2$... I am not sure where did i go wrong..

Comment: Field homomorphisms must be injective, so in particular, we can't have $\eta(\omega) = 1$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim : It can be trivial map also, right? .. :O

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition you are working with. Many people require that a field homomorphism take $1$ to $1$; this is implicit in your logic above. But in the event that the map is trivial (i.e. everything maps to $0$), your claim that $\omega^{3} = 1$ implies $\eta(\omega)^{3} = 1$ no longer holds, so I don't see the objection.

Comment: Ok Ok.. I got it

Comment: Why have you deleted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692733 ?

Comment: @DerekHolt : It was by mistake... I have undeleted it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument $\omega^3=1 \Rightarrow \eta(\omega)^3=1$ is correct, hence this equation is necessary. But it is not sufficient. We even have the stronger $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, so we can argue, that $\eta(\omega)^2+\eta(\omega)+1=0$. And this equation leaves you only with the two possibilities $\eta(\omega) \in \{\omega, \omega^2\}$ and kicks out $\eta(\omega)=1$. Of course, the reasoning of Alex Wertheim in the comments kicked that out, too. Though, my reasoning leads you to the general method: The possible images are the roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Ok Ok... Thanks :)